JavaScript - number in method is showing typeof string after I have performed a mathematical operation on it
I'm trying to figure out why something that should be a number is showing typeof equals string. Here is my code:


const goToDinner = () => {
  const menu = [
    {
      dishName: "Beef Tenderloin",
      price: 14.75,
    },
    {
      dishName: "Ribeye Steak",
      price: 17.50,
    },
    {
      dishName: "Barbecue Chicken",
      price: 13.25,
    },
  ];
  let menuList = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    menuList += `${i + 1}. ${menu[i].dishName}: $${menu[i].price}\n`;
  }
  const dinnerChoice = parseInt(prompt(
    `Please select your choice of meal:\n${menuList}`,
  ));
  if (
    !Number.isNaN(dinnerChoice) && dinnerChoice > 0 &&
    dinnerChoice <= menu.length
  ) {
    console.log(`You have chosen the ${menu[dinnerChoice - 1].dishName}.`);
  }
  const preTipTotal = parseFloat(menu[dinnerChoice - 1].price).toFixed(2);
  console.log(`The preTip amount = ${preTipTotal}.`);
  const tipPercentage = 0.095;
  const tipCost = (preTip, tipPercent) => {
    const tipResult = (preTip * tipPercent).toFixed(2);
    console.log(`The tip comes to ${tipResult}`);
    console.log(`typeof tipResult = ${typeof tipResult}.`);
    return tipResult;
  };
  console.log(`Is preTipTotal a number? ${typeof preTipTotal}`);
  const totalBill = preTipTotal + tipCost(preTipTotal, tipPercentage);
  console.log(`Your total bill is $${totalBill}.`);
};

goToDinner();



When I choose an option, say #2 - the Ribeye Steak for 17.50, the tip is 1.66. But on the last line of the function, the total shown is $17.501.66 instead of $19.16. I traced the problem down to the tipCost inner function. typeof tipResult shows it is a string. But the arguments fed into tipCost's parameters - preTipTotal and tipPercentage - are both numbers. Moreover, I perform multiplication on them and use a Number method (toFixed) for the result. So why is tipResult coming up as a string instead of a number?
I know I could probably correct the issue with a parseFloat on the call to tipCost(), but that's not enough. I need to be able to explain why tipResult is coming up as a string instead of a number, and I can't do that because it makes no sense to me.

Number.toFixed returns a string

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Only use toFixed when you wish to display the result.

Does this answer your question? .toFixed() returns a string? how can I convert that to floating number
